# Tensor product of skyscraper sheaf and canonical bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $k$, let $\mathcal{O}_x$ be the skyscraper sheaf of the residue field $k(x)$ at a closed point $x$, and let $\omega_X$ be the canonical bundle.  Assuming possibly that $\omega_X$ is ample, I believe there is an isomorphism between $\mathcal{O}_x$ and $\mathcal{O}_x \otimes \omega_X$ (at least in the derived category of coherent sheaves on $X$).  Can someone provide a reference for this fact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sheaf $O_x\otimes\omega_X$ is also skyscraper supported at $x$, and its stalk at $x$ is $k(x)\otimes \omega_X\simeq k(x)$ (because $\omega_X$ is locally free of rank $1$). So $O_x\otimes\omega_X$ is isomorphic to $O_x$. Am I wrong ?